# link_to in data-content for a bootstrap 4 popover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, href, bootstrap-4, popover, link-to

I want to put a link in the data-content of my popover.  not using <% link_to 'Save it to your events', usersavedevents_path, method: :post %> because it doesn't work, it spews over into the UI.

view

```
<div class="col-1" tabindex="0" data-container="body" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Save" data-content="Not sure if you're going? <a rel='nofollow' data-method='get' href='/usersavedevents/new?user_id=1'>Save it to your events</a> and we'll remind you closer to the start date.">
                <%= image_tag "bookmark.png", height: '25px' %>
              </div>
<script>

              $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(
                  {html : true
                  })
              })</script>
              <script>
              $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
                trigger: 'focus'
              })</script>
```

controller (I have it root_path for now just to test it out and see if i get action)

```
class UserSavedEventsController < ApplicationController
def new
    redirect_to root_path
end

def create
    redirect_to root_path   
end
end
```

routes

```
  resources :usersavedevents
```

Keep getting this error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant UsersavedeventsController
```

Comment: how did you name your file? `user_saved_events_controller.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your naming is wrong:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :user_saved_events
```

Thus the path will be `user_saved_events_path`

make sure your file name follows the Rails convention:

```
user_saved_events_controller.rb
```

Here's some doc on [rails naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)